# Calling the click event without target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
$('nvmd what is here').click(function() {
    //The Magic Code
}
```

I need to use this magic code, but it's written in such way, that I can't use it without calling the click function. Is it possible to use it without pairing it to the target, something like this, perhaps:

```
$.click(function() {
    //The Magic Code 
    //and mine
}
```

Comment: what is it that you are trying to achieve? May be it will give us an idea..

Comment: `it's written in such way, that I can't use it without calling the click function` clarify what you mean?

Comment: That mean there's a written code that I can't touch and the "magic code" works only if it called with the click event

Comment: clicked where? where will the user click?

Comment: Do you need the magic-code to work no matter where the user clicks?

Comment: are you trying to trigger the click event of the element without the user actually doing it? you can do `$('nvmd what is here').click()` after the code you already have

Comment: Are you saying you need to call the function manually? The one that is currently being called in a click event?

Comment: @Blaze Sahlzen, I need the magic code to work as IF(emulated) the user were click somewhere(or specifically to the  "nvmd what is here").  @ vahanpwns, thanks buddy, tried this in different ways(also with a delay) but didn't work. Any other ideas perhaps? The original code is only checking the click event to be true in order the magic code to work.

Comment: Following @vahanpwns 's answer, you can call magic() from any place in your script. Wherever you need the code to run..

Comment: When you say call `magic()` you are assuming that it's a declared function instead of an anonymous function or a constructor. We need more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function magic(){
    alert('abracadabra');
}
$('nvmd what is here').click(magic);
```

http://codepen.io/t3hpwninat0r/pen/Vayood

you can then do `magic();` or `$('nvmd what is here').click();` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Answers to questions are supposed to be direct and complete. Answer cannot be another question. Please use comments to ask for any clarifications you would need.